# golangci-lint complains on SQL rows not closed, despite it is closed from a goroutine

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I am using golangci-lint as part of my CI/CD. It is complaining on SQL rows not being closed, despite it is being closed from a goroutine:

```
....
    rows, err := ...
    ...
    go funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows(rows)
}
...
func funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows(rows *sql.Rows) {
    defer rows.Close()
```

The message I am getting is

> Rows/Stmt was not closed (sqlclosecheck)

Is that really a bad pattern and I should avoid doing it, or a bug with golangci-lint?
How can I make golangci-lint ignore that?

**EDIT:**

I left out an important piece from my sample code. Here is an update:

```
....
    rows, err := ...
    if err != nil {
         return ....
    }
    ...
    go funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows(rows)
}
...
func funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows(rows *sql.Rows) {
    defer rows.Close()
```

So the problem is that in case of an error before starting the goroutine, `Close` will never be called. So I had to explicitly call it, in case of an error.

Comment: You accepting point in the function ```funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows``` but you not passing reference to it when calling ```go funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows(rows)``` it should be address of rows ```funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows(&rows)```

Comment: I would call it a bad practice simply because the row closing operation is not visually paired with the acquisition operation, which is WTF for the readers.

Comment: Or lint can ignore by passing comment ```//nolint```

Comment: Based on the code you've presented, it's impossible to tell if it's even correct.  I can't tell when/if funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows() is always called, to know if it's handling closing in all cases.

I'm also not sure why you'd want to do that in a goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Analysing your code, seems like this might cause a problem.

If my understanding is correct, your code will return if your `err` is not nil. Then row will not be closed since it will not reach the `funcThatDoesSomethingWithRows`